# missing parameter type for expanded function The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5) Expected type was:?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I use Spark2.0  Dataset and DataFrame to read datas ,the code is :

```
 def func(docs: DataFrame): RDD[(String, String)] = {
   docs.select("id", "title").map{
     case Row(id: String, title: String) => (id, title)
 }}
```

but the compile error is

```
missing parameter type for expanded function The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5) Expected type was: ?
```

and i also try the way

`def func(docs: DataFrame): RDD[(String, String)] = {
   docs.select("id", "title").map{val => val match{
     case Row(id: String, title: String) => (id, title)
 }}}`  but this is not work !   the error on the 'val' is :

```
◾missing parameter type
```

how can i slove this !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can resolve it by using DataFrame.rdd

```
 // before map 
 def func(docs: DataFrame): RDD[(String, String)] = {
   docs.select("id", "title").rdd.map{
     case Row(id: String, title: String) => (id, title)
 }}

// or after map
def func(docs: DataFrame): RDD[(String, String)] = {
   docs.select("_1", "_2").map{ 
     case Row(id: String, title: String) => (id, title)
   }.rdd
}
```

Note that in Spark 1.x DataFrame.map returns RDD[R], and takes function as (Row) => R.

While in Spark 2.x Dataset.map returns Dataset[U],and takes function as (T) => U.